# Only small area of image linked/clickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to know how i can make a part of an image clickable and not the intire image. I'll add a screenshot so u can see for yourself. Ohh lol i am not allowed to post images. Here is the link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FOGv.png

I am talking about the logo on the left. Because it's a transparent png the image/clickable link is also where u don't see the image.

Sorry for my terrible english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Place a div above the image  position it to that particular area, set click only to it by assigning width and heaight

Answer (score 1):

Try using a MAP tag with AREA tags to define the clickable area(s).
e.g

```html
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing this in?

You could paste a transparent image on top of the logo and use that as the "button". Some software can make a circular image, but at least it is smaller than the whole banner.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use image maps, the old way is still functional and it fits your wish very well.

```
 <img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

 <map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
    <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
 </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place the image in a container and in that container put a link, position it absolutely over the logo. The link would be with the same dimentions as the logo, and place it where the logo starts. Here is some sample code.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Company logo" />
    <a href="link.html" class="image-link">Some text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container { position: relative; }

.image-link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: [width-of-logo]px;
    height: [height-of-logo]px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* text-indent: -9999px; */
}
```

Uncomment `text-indent: -9999px;` if you wish to not display text in the link, but still leave the text in the link, for accessibility's sake.

Comment: @daanaan if you're gonna use it could you pls mark it as the answer to your question? hope it works out for you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Woww thats quick!
i guess i'll go for the last option.

Code looks a little bit more complicated but i guess i'll figure it out. Don't want to get lazy :). Thanks guys!

```
                    <div class="site-logo">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img data-altlogo="<?php echo $alternate_logo; ?>" src="<?php echo $sitelogo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></a>
                    </div>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <div class="site-logo">
                        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>                 

            </div>
```